# Python Discord Bot NoneType Error When giving Permissions

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, nonetype

I'm currently trying to make a Discord bot that joins a server, creates a category and then creates a channel under the category. I am trying to make the Discord bot change the permissions of the default user for the channel I am making but I keep getting a NoneType error.

```
@client.event
async def on_ready(): 
    print('WE have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
    async for guild in client.fetch_guilds():  
        role_perms = discord.Permissions(send_messages=False, read_messages=True)

        await guild.create_role(name = 'Bot User', permissions = role_perms)
        newCat = await guild.create_category_channel(name = 'RSI Bot') # saves created category into variable 

        overwrites = {
            guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages = True, send_messages = False),
        }

        channel = await guild.create_text_channel('Bot Comamnds', overwrites = overwrites, category = newCat)
```

I thought I followed the documentation exactly as is, however I am getting a NoneType error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Error message:

```
Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jaden\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event        
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jaden\Documents\GitHub\Cryptocurrency-RSI-Discord-Bot\Bot.py", line 22, in on_ready
    channel = await guild.create_text_channel('Bot Comamnds', overwrites = overwrites, category = newCat)
  File "C:\Users\Jaden\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\guild.py", line 948, in create_text_channel
    data = await self._create_channel(name, overwrites, ChannelType.text, category, reason=reason, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Jaden\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\guild.py", line 844, in _create_channel
    'id': target.id
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Comment: *Where* are you getting the NoneType error?